# Is this a cyberattack? Weird loopback file system in /tmp/tmp.050Scy377O/udf_ro

Tags: linux, mount, loopback, attack-vector

I noticed a strange-looking loopback file system being mounted on my linux machine, and dug into it a little bit. Does this look like some sort of hacking attack or cyberattack to any security experts here? I don't know if this is even the right place to ask, so please direct me elsewhere as needed/appropriate.

I have more details, but I don't want to overdo my question with too much speculation. The loopback-mounted image file is about 5.7GB. The files inside the mount appear to be mostly binary data files, except (*). I ran fuser * and do not see any process having the files open at the moment.

```
% df | grep loop
Filesystem      1K-blocks       Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop14       5938680      47998   5890682   1% /tmp/tmp.050Scy377O/udf_ro

% ls -l /tmp/tmp.050Scy377O/                                                                                      total 48509
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6081740800 Sep  9 12:46 udf_512_1024_1_0.img
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root       1000 Sep  9 12:46 udf_ro/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root       4096 Sep  9 12:46 udf_rw/

% ls -l /tmp/tmp.050Scy377O/udf_ro
total 31682
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root      80 Sep  9 12:46 0/
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 5242879 Sep  9 12:46 1.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5242879 Sep  9 12:46 CaSe
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  985084 Sep  9 12:46 american-english
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5242879 Sep  9 12:46 cAsE
-rw-r--r-- 2 root root 5242879 Sep  9 12:46 hard
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     192 Sep  9 12:46 longsym -> qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm1234567890qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm1234567890oiewqfiewioqoiqoiurqruewqoiuwoieoiiuewqroreqiufieiuwrnureweriuvceoiroiewqoiricdsalkcndsakfirefoiwqeoircorejwoijfreoijojo
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     348 Sep  9 12:46 psym -> /0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17/18/19/20/21/22/23/24/25/26/27/28/29/30/31/32/33/34/35/36/37/38/39/40/41/42/43/44/45/46/47/48/49/50/51/52/53/54/55/56/57/58/59/60/61/62/63/64/65/66/67/68/69/70/71/72/73/74/75/76/77/78/79/80/81/82/83/84/85/86/87/88/89/90/91/92/93/94/95/96/97/98/99/100/101/102/103/104/105/106/107/108/109/110/111/112/p.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5242879 Sep  9 12:46 qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm1234567890qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm1234567890oiewqfiewioqoiqoiurqruewqoiuwoieoiiuewqroreqiufieiuwrnureweriuvceoiroiewqoiricdsalkcndsakfirefoiwqeoircorejwoijfreoijojo
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     172 Sep  9 12:46 sdir/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       5 Sep  9 12:46 sym -> 1.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5242879 Sep  9 12:46 ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      65 Sep  9 12:46 ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????? -> ?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
```

(*)Note: The file american-english is a dictionary in utf-8 plaintext. Seems suspect, could be dictionary attack?

Answer to request for more info:

```
% snap list
Name                    Version                     Rev    Tracking       Publisher    Notes
acrordrdc               2021.007.20091              62     latest/stable  mmtrt        -
bare                    1.0                         5      latest/stable  canonical**  base
core18                  20220830                    2560   latest/stable  canonical**  base
core20                  20220826                    1623   latest/stable  canonical**  base
gnome-3-28-1804         3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable  canonical**  -
gnome-3-38-2004         0+git.891e5bc               115    latest/stable  canonical**  -
gtk-common-themes       0.1-81-g442e511             1535   latest/stable  canonical**  -
snapd                   2.56.2                      16292  latest/stable  canonical**  snapd
wine-platform-6-stable  6.0.4                       19     latest/stable  mmtrt        -
wine-platform-runtime   v1.0                        316    latest/stable  mmtrt        -
```

Comment: 5242879 <=> 4FFFFF₁₆ = 4*64K -1. now I'd suspect this is data stored by e.g. a `snap` package, what software are you running at this moment? Also: What does `snap list` say? (add the output as a "code snippet" in your post)

Comment: Thanks. See snap list output saved above. When I upgraded from ubuntu 21 to 22, all the old /dev/loop (lots of them) went away. That /dev/loop14 only appeared days later, AFAICT. But of course your theory may still be correct. I'll check back in about 8hrs (sleep time here).

Comment: I'm still investigatiing, it may take another day or two

Comment: `file /tmp/tmp.050Scy377O/udf_512_1024_1_0.img` a mountable disk image? `dev=$(losetup f)`, `losetup $dev /tmp/tmp.050Scy377O/udf_512_1024_1_0.img` and then either it mounts or you may use e.g. `gnome-disks` or `fdisk -l` on it. `losetup -d $dev` releases the loopdev.

Comment: also check what `file ...` says about the other large files,